# Echo something before SSH prompt with pam_exec

Tags: linux, ssh, bash, shell, pam

I want to echo some text from a `pam_exec` script **after** a successful SSH login (pubkey) but **before** the script itself exits (2FA purposes).

Whatever the script prints during its execution is displayed **when the script terminates**.

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "YAY!"
sleep 2
exit 0
```

`YAY!` is printed only after 2 seconds followed by motd and command prompt. Obviously I have already added "`stdout`" in the PAM entry:

```
account    required     pam_exec.so     stdout     /etc/test/test.sh
```

This guy (https://stackoverflow.com/a/43715952/12662891) had a similar problem but I can't find out how he solved his problem.

Comment: @flix mentions the fix was "...change a pam_info statement, in the source of pam_exec, to a pam_prompt...". Looking at the source code (https://github.com/linux-pam/linux-pam/blob/master/modules/pam_exec/pam_exec.c)  for pam_exec, there's only one line where pam_info occurrs. Might not be too bad to figure out.

Comment: @ServerFault I already tried that but it's not easy as it seems, at least for me. The statements have different C signatures and I would like not to mess up something.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute a command at the end of your SSH login simply by `ssh user@host 'whoami'`. In your script pass the variable in the command and it can be used by the remote session.

Comment: Ok, maybe my question wasn't clear. If so my fault sorry. I want to execute a script using Pluggable Authentication Modules as a second factor authentication.